# Concurrent LRU cache using a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, caching, concurrency, lru

Suppose I have a concurrent cache that looks like this:

```
public class ConcurrentCache {
        private final DAO dao;
        private final Map<Integer, CompletableFuture<Account>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        
        ConcurrentCache(DAO dao) {
            this.dao = dao;
        }

        Account get(int id) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            CompletableFuture<Account> f = cache.putIfAbsent(id, new CompletableFuture<>());

            if (f == null) {
                Account a = dao.get(id);
                if (a == null)
                    a = new Account(-1);
                cache.get(id).complete(a);
            }
            
            Account a = cache.get(id).get();

            return a.id == -1 ? null : a;
        }

        interface DAO {
            Account get(int id);
        }

        static class Account {
            final int id;

            Account(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
        }
    }
```

Several threads can call `ConcurrentCache#get` concurrently without interfering with each other, given that they're requesting different accounts.

Now suppose I want to implement a LRU eviction policy in this cache using a linked list. This means that in every `ConcurrentCache#get` call I need to modify the linked list moving the requested account's node to the front of the linked list. Surely I need to synchronise this modification compromising the concurrency - one thread modifying the list will cause the others to block regardless the account id they're querying:

```
Account a = cache.get(id).get();

//move the account's node to the front

synchronized (this) {
 unlink(node);
 insert(node);
}

return a.id == -1 ? null : a;
```

It's not as bad it could have been had I synchronised the entire method. Is it as good as I can do?

Another question, how do I actually evict least recently used accounts? Suppose I did it in my synchronized block:

```
synchronized (this) {
 unlink(n);
 insert(n);
 if (cache.size() > limit) {
  cache.remove(tail.prev.id);
  unlink(tail.prev);
 }
}
```

The problem is that `cache.size()` can be larger than `limit` by more than 1. I can imagine removing the difference `cache.size() - limit` from the map in a loop but then there can be brief periods when the cache grows without bounds. A way to avoid such spikes is using a semaphore with `limit` number of permits, but again it might compromise the concurrency when the cache is full and the clients keep querying accounts which are not in the cache. What alternatives approaches can be used here?

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentHashMap already takes a lot of memory.  Your linked list would add to that, and is difficult to make lock-free.

However much memory you want to devote to this cache, you can make better use of it by using an *approximately* LRU cache with a more efficient representation.

Here are a couple ways you can do this:

### Sharded Cache

Let's say you want your cache to support N items.  Pick a prime P around sqrt(N), and then divide your cache into P LRU caches, each of which support N/P items.

Each shard would be a fully synchronized LRU cache based on `LinkedHashMap`.  Your get procedure would first use `((key.hashCode() * SOME_ODD_NUMBER) & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % P` to choose the shard for the key, and then use the cache in that shard.

### N-Way Cache

Let's say you want your cache to support N items.  Instead of using a hashmap and list, just allocate a table of size N.

Every time you allocate a new item, give it a "timestamp" using, say, `AtomicLong.getAndIncrement()'.

To perform a get, hash the full key hash code into 4 different slots.  Check each slot, and if you don't find your key, then put a new entry one of those slots -- either an empty one or the one with the smallest timestamp.

Note that unless you're careful, duplicate entries will appear in your cache with low frequency.  If that's not harmless, then you have to be careful to prevent it.